# Display csv inside firefox browser

Tags: firefox, csv, download, mime-types

I need to open a csv file within firefox. By default, it asks me to choose a download location or to open it with an external program. However, regarding the context, I have to display it straight away inside the browser as plain text, without passing by the popup screen which asks me what to do with the file.

I tried to tweak the Firefox "mimetype.rdf" in order to force the content type "text/csv" to be opened in browser. However, I don't find much information about this file, so I was more or less guessing... This is what I came out with:

```
<RDF:Description RDF:about="urn:mimetype:text/csv" 
    NC:value="text/csv"
    NC:editable="false"
    NC:description="CSV page"
    NC:fileExtensions="csv">

  <NC:handlerProp RDF:resource="urn:mimetype:handler:text/plain"/>
</RDF:Description>
```

My idea was to force firefox to treat text/csv as text/plain. This code does not work. But anyway, I managed to force content type using "Mason" firefox extension. However, when the browser sees it as a text/plain, it propose me to open it with notepad or download, does not help me much.

I tried other content types, the text/html, text/xml, it always asks me to choose an external application or download.

I tried to use several extensions, "openInBrowser" and "ViewAsText" make me able to do what I want, but I have to explicitely go in a menu and click the "view as text in the browser", no possibility to set a behavior for the content type "text/csv".

How can I explain that I want all the "text/csv" to be opened inside firefox by default?

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Is the server giving you the right mime headers?

Comment: yes, I checked the header using firebug, and I do get text/csv

Comment: By the way, the mimetype.rdf code I gave is wrong, I managed to force text/plain content type, but not from what I wrote, got a little confused... The overwrite was done by "Mason" firefox add-on. I'm rephrasing my question.

Answer (score 0):

You could have an upload field where the CSV file gets uploaded to the server. Using server-side code (ASPX for example) you could upload the file, then read the contents of the CSV file and display the results using a Response.Write to the browser.